# Strange transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain, blockchain.info

I have noticed this... 
https://blockchain.info/address/18EC8axfZZBj5rM3wfnVAZCPmuBP3v5E7r

I am waiting for the transaction of 0.748458 and 1.1147815BTC but it looks like they are received on the blockchain.  The unconfirmed transaction is 1.8632395 is the transaction total of the two, but it looks like its sent from the wallet that is waiting for the deposit.  I have checked my wallet and there is no deposit or withdrawal from 18EC8axfZZBj5rM3wfnVAZCPmuBP3v5E7r.

Is this normal as its quite worrying.
I appreciate your help and replies.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Do you own 18EC8axfZZBj5rM3wfnVAZCPmuBP3v5E7r? The 1.86 BTC transaction is being sent *from* that wallet not to it, if that is your wallet it's possible it has been compromised?

Comment: Yes, that is my wallet.  I'm wondering how a I've used this numerous times, but this was the first time from this exchange.

Comment: I have checked my wallet BTC history and there is no deposit or withdrawal of the amounts missing.  Could my wallet address been cloned to receive and then used again to send out?  
Which part could be compromised.... the person sending out the BTC or the bitcoin wallet receiving side?

Comment: I checked with the exchange that my wallet is held at and they said no deposits had been made but after an hour the BTCs were deposited.. does the exchanges hold a master wallet where they send the coins to the clients?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction is not confirmed, as such both outputs in this transaction are not confirmed (and all the others as well). There is a ~50 Bytes per Satoshi transaction fee, and this is way too low to be taken into consideration by any miner. There are many, many transactions offering higher fees, so you might need to wait for quite some time.

More info here: [Why is my transaction not getting confirmed and what can I do about it?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/9046/why-is-my-transaction-not-getting-confirmed-and-what-can-i-do-about-it)

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I did not set the transaction fee, it was from the exchange that i sent it out from.

Comment: yup, this is indeed funny. There are many bitcoins in the tx (+22), a value of +220.000 Euros, but tx fees in the low, low, low range ... the tx has a length of ~4000 Bytes, with 50 Satoshi/byte is 200.000 Satoshis, is roughly 20 Euro tx fee...

Comment: I see, i just checked the exchange i sent it out from there is no option to increase fee for tx.  What can i do now? 
Thanks

Comment: not much (?), but following advice in the link above (which is probably contacting your provider).